# Wireguard Site to Site Issue - Site B Host can't reach Site A Host

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard

**Update**

For anyone who finds this in the future, the issue was resolved. I was looking at WireGuard, thinking it was the problem originally and didn't examine my environments too closely. In this case, I foolishly assumed my OpenStack environment 'Allow All' security group allowed all traffic to go through, but there were additional security layers I didn't understand. After finding out how to disable the 'port' security on OpenStack, it worked! Now, I need to figure out how to allow the traffic I want through with the security up.

The lesson here is to look at the network security of your environment.

Thanks to everyone who helped.

---

I'm trying to configure a site to site VPN setup using WireGuard. Currently, I only have 2 sites, one acting as the server and the other as the client. The problem I'm running into is that no matter which site acts as the client or server, hosts in Site B can never communicate properly with hosts in Site A.

For example, pinging a host in **Site A** from **Site B**'s host results in no reply. I'll post some of the network traffic I've captured from host to host. It seems like the packets are being silently dropped when returning? Does that seem, right? And if so, does anyone know why this could be happening? The ping from the other direction works without issues (Site A to Site B).

**Subnet Info**

172.17.0.0/24 = Site A

10.30.21.0/24 = Site B

**Ping Path**

*Site_B_Host (Ping) > Site_B_WG > Site_A_WG > Site_A_Host*

**Traffic Capture**

Site_B_Host (Ping)

```
  1 0.000000000   10.30.21.6 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=45/11520, ttl=64
  2 0.999916129   10.30.21.6 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=46/11776, ttl=64
  3 1.999942887   10.30.21.6 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=47/12032, ttl=64
  4 2.999850129   10.30.21.6 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=48/12288, ttl=64
  ...
```

Site_B_WG (eth0)

```
  1 0.000000000   10.30.21.6 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=46/11776, ttl=64
  2 0.014949872 172.17.0.233 -> 10.30.21.6   ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x2a27, seq=46/11776, ttl=62 (request in 1)
  3 1.000135163   10.30.21.6 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=47/12032, ttl=64
  4 1.001890395 172.17.0.233 -> 10.30.21.6   ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x2a27, seq=4
...
```

Site_A_WG (eth0)

```
  1 0.000000000  172.17.0.10 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=47/12032, ttl=62
  2 0.000402204 172.17.0.233 -> 172.17.0.10  ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x2a27, seq=47/12032, ttl=64 (request in 1)
  3 0.999750017  172.17.0.10 -> 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a27, seq=48/12288, ttl=62
  4 1.000161082 172.17.0.233 -> 172.17.0.10  ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x2a27, seq=48/12288, ttl=64 (request in 3)
...
```

Site_A_Host (eth0)

```
    1 0.000000000  172.17.0.10 → 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a41, seq=1/256, ttl=62
    2 1.000018292  172.17.0.10 → 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a41, seq=2/512, ttl=62
    3 1.999918921  172.17.0.10 → 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a41, seq=3/768, ttl=62
    4 2.999954197  172.17.0.10 → 172.17.0.233 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x2a41, seq=4/1024, ttl=62
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the network configuration (eg: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule`), the wireguard configuration (either wg-quick config, feel free to obfuscate the keys or multiple wg commands) of the two wg endpoints, and the firewall+ NAT rules in place (eg: `iptables-save -c` or `nft list ruleset`)?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I actually just found out what the issue was and will post the update above.

Comment: You're supposed to answer your own question with a solution, not to update the question to tell it's solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

For anyone who finds this in the future, the issue was resolved. I was looking at WireGuard, thinking it was the problem originally and didn't examine my environments too closely. In this case, I foolishly assumed my OpenStack environment 'Allow All' security group allowed all traffic to go through, but there were additional security layers I didn't understand. After finding out how to disable the 'port' security on OpenStack, it worked! Now, I need to figure out how to allow the traffic I want through with the security up.

The lesson here is to look at the network security of your environment.

Thanks to everyone who helped.